# How can I handle events, in Fabric.js, on a individual object within a group?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Lets say i have 3 circles and add them to a group.

```
var circle1 = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'red',
  left: 0
});
var circle2 = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'green',
  left: 100
});
var circle3 = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'blue',
  left: 200
});

var group = new fabric.Group([ circle1, circle2, circle3 ], {
  left: 200,
  top: 100
});

canvas.add(group);
```

How can I handle mouse events for just, let's say, circle1?

Or in other words, how can I know which of the objects, in the group, the mouse clicked on?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047094/fabricjs-catch-click-on-object-inside-group

Comment: Pretty sure i asked first. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you group objects together , you make the group object to behave as an object, so it rotates, it moves, it scales, it listens to events like any other individual object. 
you cant listen to any events on the individual objects just because now all together are form one object only.

of course the group object has item methods item(index), getObjects() so you can get the individual objects and get/update their properties.

1. a custom solution could be to :

   1. get the mouse:down event
   2. get the pointer position
   3. read through all _objects of the group object
   4. compare the position of the mouse pointer to the position of the activeObj._objects[item]
   5. if it fits you have found the child object

something like this:

```
canvas.observe('mouse:down', function (options)
{
    pos = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
    console.log("POSITION"+pos);
        activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
        if (Math.abs(pos.x - activeObj.left) < 10 && Math.abs(pos.y - activeObj.top) < 30 && Math.abs(pos.y - activeObj.top) > 10) {
            console.log("connector selected");            
        }    
});
```

another discussion is made here for that issue, if you would like to take a look: 
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/485

hope helps, good luck

Comment: Thanks for this. However, i noticed there is a evented property on the group object. Its says setting it to false, events are propagated through. I thought this would have been the solution but apparently it does nothing because setting it to false still handles events.  What is the purpose of the evented property then?

Answer (score 0):

When the events fires you can inspect the target object through the canvas listener callBack, I am not sure if the object has a property for the shape type. Else you could assign a property on adding the circle saying that its a circle, the pick it up through the event.

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target); // should contain info on the clicked object
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but e.target only returns the group object containing the array. It doesn't say which object in the array/group was clicked on.

Comment: Ah, yes, thats true, is there no way to use the e.target to identify the group you need, then reference the actual group objects items?

http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/#groups

Answer (score -2):

```
  circle2.on('mouseup', function(event) {
    console.log(`circle2 mouseup`);
  });
```

Comment: This works on an individual object but not when the object is in a group