# FabricJS Catch click on object inside group

Tags: onclick, fabricjs

I have tried many thing like calculating location, handling with the event we do have in original fabricjs. Does any have done this before?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible to listen for events on the inner object by adding the option: `subTargetCheck: true` to the fabric.Group object.

```
    // create a group
    let group = new fabric.Group([circle, rect], {
        subTargetCheck: true
    });

    circle.on('mousedown', function(e) { 
        // e.target should be the circle
        console.log(e.target);
    });
```

Comment: According to their [changelog](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-changelog) it was released in version 1.6.3.

Comment: I guess this is the solution for our days.

Comment: While this is the correct approach (according to documentation) I have encountered some issues: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/3906

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded fabricjs from  [asturur repo](https://github.com/asturur/fabric.js).
build fabric.js file

```
node build.js modules=ALL exclude=json,gestures
```

and it works!

Then you can use events on objects in the groups.

```
canvas._objects[0]._objects[0].on('mousedown', function(e){ this.stroke = 'black'});
```

In my app i decided to search for events from mousedown callback

```
group.on('mousedown', function(e){
    var innerTarget  = group._searchPossibleTargets(e.e);
    console.log(innerTarget);
});

group._searchPossibleTargets = function(e) {
    var pointer = this.canvas.getPointer(e, true);
    var i = objects.length,
        normalizedPointer = this.canvas._normalizePointer(this, pointer);

    while (i--) {
        if (this.canvas._checkTarget(normalizedPointer, this._objects[i])) {
            return this._objects[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: on my side doesn't works... It's returning all no matter where i click....

Answer (score 1):

In FabricJS once the objects have been assembled into a group the Events are only happening there, even the selected events - so you cannot detect which of the items in the group are being selected.  Inside the event handler

```
var g = new fabric.Group([ rect, text ], {
g.on('mousedown', function(e) {
    // Inspect, for a collection of the objects in this group
    this._objects
});
```

Even attaching event handlers to the objects before assembly into the group the handlers don't fire :(

Comment: What I'm saying is that Fabric doesn't support what you want w/o editing it's core or over-riding some routines/events handlers

Comment: Yes, i know that. That is really useful thing, i am sure that someone has done this.

Comment: How do i get the same for dblclick ?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
// create a group
let group = new fabric.Group([circle, rect], {
    subTargetCheck: true
});

canvas.on('mouse:down', function (e) {
// clicked item will be
  console.log(e.subTargets[0])  
});
```

Comment: How do i get the subTargets for dblclick ?

Comment: it doesn't work for me, https://jsfiddle.net/c7osmL3r/4/

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to be able to comment on an existing answer so here goes. I am using v2.X of Fabric and all of the existing solutions do not work. Either console errors for methods that no longer exist or always `false` in case of `containsPoint` so I built my own.

```
js
const getSelectedObject = (target, e) => {
  const point = target.canvas.getPointer(e, false);

  const objects = findSubTargets(target, []);

  const objectIndex = objects
    .reduce((reduction, object, index) => {
      reduction.push(
        getBoundingPoints(
          object,
          index === 0 ? 0 : reduction[0].start.x,
          index === 0 ? 0 : reduction[0].start.y
        )
      );

      return reduction;
    }, [])
    .reverse()
    .findIndex((bounds) => pointIsInBounds(point, bounds));

  return objects.reverse()[objectIndex];
};
```

and the helper functions

```
js
const getBoundingPoints = (object, deltaX, deltaY) => {
  const coords = object.get("aCoords");

  const x1 = coords.tl.x + deltaX;
  const y1 = coords.tl.y + deltaY;
  const x2 = coords.br.x + deltaX;
  const y2 = coords.br.y + deltaY;

  return {
    start: { x: x1, y: y1 },
    finish: { x: x2, y: y2 }
  };
};


const pointIsInBounds = (point, bounds) => {
  const xIsInBounds = point.x >= bounds.start.x && point.x <= bounds.finish.x;
  const yIsInBounds = point.y >= bounds.start.y && point.y <= bounds.finish.y;

  return xIsInBounds && yIsInBounds;
};


const findSubTargets = (target, objects) => {
  if (target.isType("group")) {
    objects.push(target);
    target.forEachObject((object) => findSubTargets(object, objects));
  }

  return objects;
};
```

I've tested this with simple groups, nested groups and groups inside groups inside groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `subTarget` to the group. The subtarget object will be added inside target event.

```
let group = new fabric.Group([circle, rect], {
    subTargetCheck: true
});

canvas.on('mouse:down', (event) => {
    const { subTargets } = event; // subTargets will include circle object
    .... 
})
```

Comment: is this code still working? I've tried the exact same code and subTargets is always an empty array

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps you http://jsfiddle.net/UKbaseduser/Kt9Mk/1/

```
$("#1").click(function(){
  ZoomIn('tmp1');
});
$("#2").click(function(){
  ZoomOut('tmp1');
});
$("#3").click(function(){
  ZoomIn('tmp2');
});
$("#4").click(function(){
  ZoomOut('tmp2');
});

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({ left: 150, top: 150, width: 100, height: 100, fill: 'green'});
var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({ left: 250, top: 250, width: 100, height: 100, fill: 'green'});
rect1.grp='tmp1';
rect2.grp='tmp1';
var c = new fabric.Circle({
        left: 200,
        top: 200,
        radius: 50,
        fill: 'red',
        opacity:0.8
      });
c.grp='tmp2';
canvas.add(rect1);
canvas.add(rect2);
canvas.add(c);
canvas.renderAll();

function ZoomIn(inGrp){
    var SCALE_FACTOR = 1.2;
    var objects = canvas.getObjects();
    objects.forEach(function(obj){
        if (obj.grp==inGrp){     
            var scaleX = obj.scaleX;
            var scaleY = obj.scaleY;
            var left = obj.left;
            var top = obj.top;

            var tempScaleX = scaleX * SCALE_FACTOR;
            var tempScaleY = scaleY * SCALE_FACTOR;
            var tempLeft = left * SCALE_FACTOR;
            var tempTop = top * SCALE_FACTOR;
            obj.scaleX = tempScaleX;
            obj.scaleY = tempScaleY;
            obj.left = tempLeft;
            obj.top = tempTop;
            obj.setCoords();
            }
        });
    canvas.renderAll();
 }
function ZoomOut(inGrp){
    var SCALE_FACTOR = 1.2;
    var objects = canvas.getObjects();
    objects.forEach(function(obj){
        if (obj.grp==inGrp){     
            var scaleX = obj.scaleX;
            var scaleY = obj.scaleY;
            var left = obj.left;
            var top = obj.top;

            var tempScaleX = scaleX * 1/SCALE_FACTOR;
            var tempScaleY = scaleY * 1/SCALE_FACTOR;
            var tempLeft = left * 1/SCALE_FACTOR;
            var tempTop = top * 1/SCALE_FACTOR;
            obj.scaleX = tempScaleX;
            obj.scaleY = tempScaleY;
            obj.left = tempLeft;
            obj.top = tempTop;
            obj.setCoords();
            }
        });
    canvas.renderAll();
 }
```

Also there is similar discussion going on over here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabricjs/hQwHxGfyx6w may be it throws you some pointers.

Comment: on your link of jsfiddle is empty canvas. You function look to do zoom in and zoom out. Nothing on clicking object inside an group.