# how do I create a movable background image to which movable foreground objects are pinned with Fabric JS?

Tags: fabricjs

I want to have an image, on top of which I can mark points (which I should be able to drag across the image).

The image is also going to be bigger than the canvas, so I want to be able to drag it as well, but while doing so keeping it in the background, and moving all the marks on it along with it.

I thought using a Group, disabling the controls of all objects and disabling selection for the Canvas would do the trick:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.hasControls = fabric.Object.prototype.hasBorders = false;
let fabricCanvasObj = new fabric.Canvas(canvas);
fabricCanvasObj.scene = new fabric.Group([new fabric.Image(img)]);
fabricCanvasObj.add(fabricCanvasObj.scene);
fabricCanvasObj.selection = false;
```

But now I want that on mouse:down a new point will be added, unless the mouse is over an already created point, so that when the user want to move that mark, no new mark is created in its place, and I want to move that individual point instead of the whole group.

But the event.target is the whole group, not the individual object in that group.

I've then followed the solution here: [FabricJS Catch click on object inside group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047094/fabricjs-catch-click-on-object-inside-group)
Which suggested using

```
{subTargetCheck: true}
```

But this causes an exception to be thrown once I add an object to the group after it's been created.

How should I go about this?

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: Here is an example of sync objects to another one. http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/2Y587/ Maybe this can help you.